# ver vídeo off-line

Tags: banco-de-dados

Atualmente estou criando um site para assistir filmes e séries, onde a pessoa possa baixar o filme e logo após isso ser disponibilizado ela ver o mesmo dentro do site, igual a Netflix faz (deixando a pessoa baixar o episódio da série para assistir off-line). queria saber um código que me ajude nisso, ou então um direcionamento de onde eu possa aprender sobre, pois eu já pesquisei e não encontrei nada relacionado ao tema.

Comment: Olá Wesley. Não duplique perguntas, revise a pergunta original seguindo as [**orientações já passadas** para ti na pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/586643/rodar-videos-offline-no-site#comment1022404_586643). Os comentários aqui serão desabilitados para que continue na pergunta original. Note que para reabrir uma pergunta é necessário editar a pergunta original seguindo as orientações.